# SQL Server counter column that increments when a new record has been added

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, increment

I'm working on a stored procedure that needs to keep track of reports that have run each day. If a report has run multiple times, I need a column that increments each time the report is run. I'm not sure how to make it keep track of ReportID or ReportName without explicitly naming each report to keep track of. Using SQL Server 2012, let's call the table ProcessMaster.

```
Time  ReportID   ReportName  (Increment Column)
----  --------   ----------  ------------------
7:00    2145      Job1               1
7:30    2145      Job1               2
7:30    2146      Another            1
8:00    2145      Job1               3
8:30    2146      Another            2
```

Comment: Just going to have to update the column yourself.

Comment: you can create trigger on insert , and manually update no in trigger

Comment: Look into SQL Server [`SEQUENCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an option of not having that column at all, by generating rank on the fly:

```
SELECT *, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ReportId ORDER BY Time) as IncrementColumn
FROM ProcessMaster
```

If you want that field to be stored you have options:

- Write a trigger
- Increment in your application layer

Comment: I will give this a try. Thank you.